# ¿Como poner un item seleccionado de una listview?

Tags: android, android-fragment, listview

Tengo el el siguiente fragment con una listview adaptada, nesecito que al aparecer este fragment me aparezca el item 0 ($ 2.000.00) seleccionado con un background que cree pero al momento de aparecer el fragment no hay nada seleccionado, aca les dejo lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debido a que me piden que publique mi clase adapter y stack overflow no me lo permite por "exceso de codigo en la publicacion", borro las clases anteriores y les dejo el adapter

**AdapterFragmentPanelDinero.java**

```
public class AdapterFragmentPanelDinero extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] dinero;
private String[] numero;

public AdapterFragmentPanelDinero(Context context, String[] dinero) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dinero = dinero;

    numero = new String[15];

    iniciarArreglo();
}

public void iniciarArreglo(){

    numero[0] = "15";
    numero[1] = "14";
    numero[2] = "13";
    numero[3] = "12";
    numero[4] = "11";
    numero[5] = "10";
    numero[6] = "9";
    numero[7] = "8";
    numero[8] = "7";
    numero[9] = "6";
    numero[10] = "5";
    numero[11] = "4";
    numero[12] = "3";
    numero[13] = "2";
    numero[14] = "1";
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dinero.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dinero[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @NonNull View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_panel_dinero, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textoDinero = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textoDineroPregunta);
    TextView textoNumero = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textoNumeroPregunta);

    if (dinero[position].equals("$ 30.000")) {
        textoDinero.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    if (dinero[position].equals("$ 180.000")) {
        textoDinero.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    if (dinero[position].equals("$ 2.000.000")) {
        textoDinero.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    textoDinero.setText(dinero[position]);
    textoNumero.setText(numero[position]);

    return convertView;
}}
```

Comment: Eso debes programarlo en el adapter generas una función para setear el valor seleccionado y lo llamas desde tu activity. Si tienes el proyecto en algún repositorio compartelo y te hago la prueba de concepto con tu código.

Comment: coloca tu clase adapter alli es donde se debe de hacer

Comment: No coloqué mi clase adapter porque me dice "parece que tu publicación contiene mucho código" algo asi

Answer (score 0):

Según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10064393/323149) respuesta en inglés, debes activar la lista para que los elementos puedan tener un estado seleccionado. Por defecto la lista está puesta como que no admite elementos seleccionados:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Además, si no lo estás haciendo ya, tienes que aplicar el estilo que has definido (Background_item_fragment_selected) a cada fila de tu lista